# Markdown errors in blog post about RAG

Tags: bug, markdown, code-formatting, blog

*Editor note: While there's at least one other applicable tag, I'd like to leave it at four tags to allow for a `status-*` tag.*

In [this blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/10/18/retrieval-augmented-generation-keeping-llms-relevant-and-current/?cb=1), there's an unusual use of a code block to quote LLM output.

Here's what the problematic section looks like:

> [image]

**Error #1**: Judging by context, it seems like what's in the freehand red circle is likely LLM-generated, and should be included in the code block/quoted text

**Error #2**: Can blockquote formatting be used instead of a monospaced code block? You're *quoting* something, after all. If a code block must be used, can syntax highlighting please be disabled?

Comment: RAG = [retrieval-augmented generation](https://research.ibm.com/blog/retrieval-augmented-generation-RAG)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the catch and suggestion. I've switched them all to quote formatting.

Comment: Thanks! Not sure if it was intentional, but you may want it to be one continuous blockquote rather than a bunch of smaller ones (assuming you have `> text here[blank line]>more text`, you'll need a `>` on the blank line to have the blockquote be continuous)